# TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined when I changed class to function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVWt1.png)

```
const Home = () => {
  React.state = {
    activeIndex: 0,
    animating: false,
  }

  React.setActiveIndex = (i) => {
    this.setState({ activeIndex: i });
  }

  React.setAnimating= (v) => {
    this.setState({ animating: v });
  }

  React.next = () => {
    if (this.state.animating) return;
    const nextIndex =
      this.state.activeIndex === items.length - 1
        ? 0
        : this.state.activeIndex + 1;
    this.setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
  };

  React.previous = () => {
    if (this.state.animating) return;
    const nextIndex =
      this.state.activeIndex === 0
        ? items.length - 1
        : this.state.activeIndex - 1;
    this.setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
  };

  React.goToIndex = (newIndex) => {
    if (this.state.animating) return;
    this.setActiveIndex(newIndex);
  };

  React.slides = items.map((item) => {
    return (
      <CarouselItem
        onExiting={() => this.setAnimating(true)}
        onExited={() => this.setAnimating(false)}
        key={item.src}
      >
        <img src={item.src} alt={item.altText} />
        <CarouselCaption
          captionText={item.caption}
          captionHeader={item.caption}
        />
      </CarouselItem>
    );
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    Aos.init({ duration: 2000 })
  }, [])
  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
        <div style={{ position: "absolute", width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "#29323cb3", zIndex: 2 }}>
        </div>
        <Carousel style={{ position: "relative" }}
          activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
          next={this.next}
          previous={this.previous}
        >
          <CarouselIndicators
            items={items}
            activeIndex={this.state.activeIndex}
            onClickHandler={this.goToIndex}
          />
          {this.slides}
          <CarouselControl
            direction="prev"
            directionText="Previous"
            onClickHandler={this.previous}
          />
          <CarouselControl
            direction="next"
            directionText="Next"
            onClickHandler={this.next}
          />

        </Carousel>

      </div>    </>
  );

}

Home.propTypes = {};

export default Home;
```

I wanted to change this component from class to function and then I got this error.
I also got "ReferenceError: state is not defined" and "TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined"
I wanted to change from class to function to add aos animation.
So how can I solve these errors.
The problem is mainly with the code of bootstrap slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `this` inside the function component. And you need to refactor your state using `useState` hook.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const [state, setState] = useState({
    activeIndex: 0,
    animating: false,
})
```

To to the state changes you can do it like this

if you need to change `activeIndex`,

```
const setActiveIndex = (i) => {
   setState((prevState) => { ...prevState, activeIndex: i });
}
```

if you need to change `activeIndex`,

```
const setAnimating= (v) => {
    setState((prevState) => { ...prevState, animating: v });
}
```

You should change `this.state.activeIndex` instances to `state.activeIndex`. Same applies to `animating`

You should remove `this` from function references as well. For Ex:
Instead of,

```
this.setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
```

it should be,

```
setActiveIndex(nextIndex);
```

Hope this helps to do the refactoring!!

Comment: @Sadeen Alaa, check this out !!